# How do I create an "Environment Variable Setter"?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, design-patterns, typescript

I have a NodeJS/Typescript project.

In `server.js`, I want to set my environment variables from a `.env` file. To achieve this, I am using the [`dotenv` npm package](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme).

However, rather than leaving everything hanging in `server.ts`, I want to encapsulate this code. The solution I've come up is as follows.

The goal is for my project to adhere to SOLID and GRASP principles.

In `server.ts` I have the following:

```
import { EnvVarsSetter } from "@server/controllers/env_vars_setter/env_vars_setter";

new EnvVarsSetter().init(".env.development");
```

In `src/controllers/env_vars_setter/env_vars_setter.ts` I have the following:

```
import path from "path";

export class EnvVarsSetter {
    public init(fileName: string): void {
        const result = require("dotenv").config({
            path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), fileName),
        });

        if (result.error) {
            throw result.error;
        }

        console.log(`Successfully parsed and loaded env vars`);
    }
}
```

Is this good design? Any suggestions on how to achieve my goal in a better way?

Comment: I would be tempted to export the function directly, unless you have a reason to use a class specifically

Comment: @TedBrownlow I don't have a great reason to use a class other than the fact that I'm trying to use an object oriented approach to designing my entire nodejs app. I'm using a Java approach where everything is a class haha. Curious to get your thoughts on this.

Comment: My main thought is just that setupEnvironmentVariables() would be more transparent in its naming. When I see a class being used, I assume there's some sort of state / configuration it can hold, which would give the illusion of something more complicated. Either way though, your abstractions make sense :)